# Why does my copy function create lists with double the length of the original list?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, copy

I created a function that copies a list and returns the new list. For some reason the function returns a list with double the length of the original list.

Why does the list that is returned have double the length of the original?

```
first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
def kopi(alist = [], blist = []):
    for element in alist:
        blist.append(element)
    return blist

print(kopi(alist = first))
print("length:", len(kopi(alist = first)))
```

I also know that the easier way to copy a list is:

```
import copy as cp
first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
second = cp.copy(first)
print(second)
print("length:", len(second))
```

So why does the kopi function create a list with double the size?
I'd also like to know how the copy.copy() works in python if possible.

Comment: lmfao nvm I got it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I included the list that I wanted to return as an argument in kopi

```
def kopi(alist = [], blist = []):
```

Here is the revised kopi function:

```
first = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

def kopi(alist = []):
    blist = []
    for element in alist:
        blist.append(element)
    return blist

print(kopi(alist = first))
print("length:", len(kopi(alist = first)))
```